# Find the methods setup on mock using MOQ

Tags: c#, moq

Is there any way to list all the mocked methods (Setups) on a Mock?

Lets say, I create mock as following:

```
Mock<IAnInterface> aMock = new Mock<IAnInterface>();
aMock.Setup(am => am.Execute()).Returns(true);
```

Now, i need to find if `Execute` has been setup on `aMock`?

Comment: Just curious - why do you need that?

Comment: One of the testcase is failing and could not find the root cause. so thought if it is possible to see the mocked methods. just out of curiosity. :)

Comment: How large is your testcase that you cannot just look at the code and see what is mocked.....

Comment: @JustinPihony: actually in test case it is mocked. but while debugging i see different object. i.e ObjectID set in test case is not shown when control reaches src.

Comment: Can you provide that example? It sounds like more of a problem with your test setup

Answer (score 4):

The Mock<> type will have a private Moq.SetupCollection named 'Setups'.  While Moq.SetupCollection has a private List<Moq.Setup> named 'setups'.

[Easy to check while debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7Gdm.png)

Or you can do so with reflection:

```
var bindings = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
var setupCollectionProperty = Mapper.GetType().GetProperty("Setups", bindings);
var setupCollection = setupCollectionProperty.GetValue(Mapper);
var setupList = setupCollection.GetType().GetField("setups", bindings);
var setups = setupList.GetValue(setupCollection);
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of way of interrogating MOQ (programmatically) about what setups are configured but, running MOQ 4.0, it does list, in the test failed details, which setups were configured. 
[image: Moq reporting on configured setups]